# Why is there no operator<< for std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, unique-ptr

[util.smartptr.shared.io] in the C++11 standard mandates an `operator<<` for
`shared_ptr`s:

```
template<class E, class T, class Y>
basic_ostream<E, T>& operator<< (basic_ostream<E, T>& os, shared_ptr<Y> const& p);
```

However unless I'm missing it, I see nothing similar in [unique.ptr], and the
reference on [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) agrees. Is there a reason for the
difference?

Comment: I'm not sure that question is answerable. The reason is that nobody has put it into the standard (yet), but is that what you wanted to hear?

Comment: @KerrekSB Presumably he just wants to confirm that it's similar to `make_unique`.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's actually an answer. I believe the question is "Is there a fundamental reason for this, or is it just an omission?"

Comment: @Angew: Well, there isn't a documented reason in the present standard for not having this, but you should check the original document proposing `unique_ptr`. My bet is that simply nobody thought about adding this feature. It's not even an omission as much as it is a non-presence. The standard grows in small increments that are often disconnected, and there isn't some overall enforcement of consistency. If you think this is inconsistent and should be fixed, send a paper :-) Next meeting is in May.

Comment: Note, by the way, that `operator<<` ignores deleters. In `shared_ptr` the deleter is type-erased, which would have greatly complicated `operator<<`. For `unique_ptr`, it makes more sense to serialize the deleter, but that would be inconsistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a reason for the difference?

No, there isn't. Just as with `make_unique` this is an "oversight" and should be added in future (if someone can be bothered to send a proposal).
In the meantime you can output `ptr.get()` instead, or - if not afraid of undefined behavior:

```
#if __cplusplus <= 201600 // Some time in future
namespace std {
    template <class E, class T, class Y, class D>
    basic_ostream<E, T>& operator<< (basic_ostream<E, T>& os,
                                     unique_ptr<Y, D> const& p) {
        return os << p.get();
    }
}
#endif
```

---

That is undefined according to [namespace.std]:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to 
>   namespace `std` […] unless
>   otherwise specified.

... and the above is not specifically allowed for this matter. However, this kind of undefined behavior is fine and can be invoked without any impacts whatsoever.

Comment: `+1`, but you might want to expand on what the UB is here (and perhaps how harmful/harmless it could be in practice).

Comment: @Angew Wait, wasn't that already discussed a bazillion times on SO? I thought that was common to everyone...

Comment: Obligatory unfunny nasal demons reference.

Comment: @Columbo Your call. Just look at it from the POV of someone who lands on this question&answer from Google, without even being an SO member.

Comment: @remyabel Well, this is the type of UB with which you can normally get away in practice without any harmful consequences; that's why I added the comment.

Comment: @Angew The answer should definitely be complete, however, I do get tired of seeing people use the same cliche definition of UB over and over.

Comment: There are safer ways to emulate adding overloads to `std::`, for example `namespace extstd { using namespace std; }` and then within your own namespace, `using namespace std = extstd;`.

Comment: @Angew The harmful consequence here is that a modification to `<memory>` won't port to anyone else's environment. The source code becomes useless as soon as anything happens to the build system, such as a compiler upgrade, etc.

Comment: @Potatoswatter In practice, it makes more sense to do this in your own header file, not in `<memory>`. BTW, would your solution with `extstd` etc. work with ADL?

Comment: @Angew Ech, you would have to do `using namespace extstd;` which would suck because that transitively brings in `namespace std`. The next is to put the overload in `namespace ext` and let `extstd` bring in `std` and `ext` separately. Anyway, better alternatives exist.

Comment: [Why not `using namespace extstd;` in the client code but no `using namespace std;` in extstd, but instead explicit `std::` in the types?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/138e33cb107a88f3)

Comment: @leemes Because that doesn't work with ADL. (i.e. that will [not work in templates like `ostream_iterator`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8698a7b252f1db0) of the standard library).